# Representing tree of nodes as lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have two sets of data A and B, A are the starting nodes and B are the ending nodes. In each set there is the number of the node, the X coord and Y coord for that node as shown below. The table is read as node 0 is connected to node 1 and node 1 is connected to node 2, node 0 is also connected to node 3 and so on.

```
  A          X_A           Y_A             B            X_B            Y_B
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0           x_0           y_0             1            x_1            y_1
 1           x_1           y_1             2            x_2            y_2
 0           x_0           y_0             3            x_3            y_3
 2           x_2           y_2             4            x_4            y_4
 0           x_0           y_0             5            x_5            y_5
 3           x_3           y_3             6            x_6            y_6
 1           x_1           y_1             7            x_7            y_7
```

Each list is an array so in total there is six arrays.

I would like to extract the data so I can read each segment of lines by its coordinates. A segment of lines is defined by a collection of nodes whose start and end are either an intersection node or an end node: intersection node is connected to more than two other nodes and end node is connected to only one other node.

In this example the end results should be:

```
[(x_0, y_0),(x_5, y5)]
[(x_0, y_0),(x_3, y_3),(x_6, y_6)]
[(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1)]
[(x_1, y_1),(x_7, y_7)]
[(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),(x_4, y_4)]
```

I am quite confused on how to do this with python, any help is appreciated!

Comment: So if you look on it like a `graph` you are searching for a list of ways for all the leaves.

Comment: Yes exactly, but how to do that in python?

Comment: why is the end result:

`[(x_0, y_0),(x_5, y5)]`
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_3, y_3),(x_6, y_6)]`
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1)]`
`[(x_1, y_1),(x_7, y_7)]`
`[(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),(x_4, y_4)]`

and not:
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_5, y5)]`
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_3, y_3),(x_6, y_6)]`
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1),(x_7, y_7)]`
`[(x_0, y_0),(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),(x_4, y_4)]`

Comment: Well I recommend you to represent the graph as a [Adjacency List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/) and then write a recursive code to print the lists.

Comment: Because 1 is an intersection node connected to three other nodes

Comment: I am going to work with as many as 1,000,000 nodes, adjacency list won't do as matrix will be huge

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a simple DFS will do the trick. I define the middle nodes as thoses
who have exactly two neighbours. You define two rules:

- We can't start with a middle node and we can't stop with a middle node.
- Every segment has at least two nodes (implicit).

The code:

```
class SegmentFinder():
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        # create the adjacency lists
        self.__d = {}
        self.__reverse_d = {}
        for a,b in zip(A,B):
            self.__d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
            self.__reverse_d.setdefault(b, []).append(a)

    def find(self):
        for n in self.__d:
            if not self.__is_middle_node(n): # we can't start with a middle node
                yield from self.__dfs([n])

    def __dfs(self, segment):
        # We don't need to store the visited nodes, since we start with a non middle
        # node. If it has 1 neighbour, we won't be back. If it has more than 2,
        # then it will end the search.
        n = segment[-1]
        if len(segment) == 1 or self.__is_middle_node(n): # we can't stop with a middle node
            for n2 in self.__d[n]:
                yield from self.__dfs(segment + [n2])
        else: # a segment has at least two nodes
            yield segment

    def __is_middle_node(self, n):
        """Exactly two neighbours"""
        return len(self.__d.get(n, [])) == 1 and len(self.__reverse_d.get(n, [])) == 1

s = SegmentFinder(A, B)
list(s.find())
# [[1, 2, 4], [1, 7], [0, 3, 6], [0, 1], [0, 5]]
```

To add the coordinates, just map the nodes in the path with their x,y. For any graph algorithm, it is usually easier to work only on nodes `id` and to add the "ornements" after:

```
coords = dict(zip(A+B, zip(xa+xb,ya+yb)))
[coords[n] for path in s.find() for n in path]
```